# Unity IF Statement running when not supposed to

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, if-statement

Need Help. I'm making a input manager for this game and a part of the code not working or is working but when its not needed. The part of code is to invoke a function that invoke a action. Just have a look for your self

```
private List<Action<object, int, string>> valueChange;
public event Action<object, int, string> OnValueChange 
{
    add
    {
        if (valueChange == null)
            valueChange = new List<Action<object, int, string>>();
        valueChange.Add(value);
    }
    remove
        { valueChange.Remove(value); }
}

private void InvokeChange(object o, int i, string s)
{
    valueChange ??= new List<Action<object, int, string>>();

    valueChange?.ForEach(a => a.Invoke(o, i, s));
}

public void SetValue(object[] v)
{
    if (values.Count <= ID[ID.Length - 1])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            values.Add(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] != values[ID[i]]) // the if statment thats not working
        {
            InvokeChange(v[i], ID[i], SID[i]);
        }
        values[ID[i]] = v[i];
    }
}
```

And the file that makes the uses OnValueChange

```
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    moveInput = InputRegister.Instance.Register("Move");
    moveInput.OnValueChange += (v, id, sid) =>
    {
        if (id == 0)
            Debug.Log((float)v);
    };
}
```

Instead of calling one it calls multiple times. I try debugging and it said that the v[i] != values[ID[i]] is false but is stills run that lines of code.
Again please help, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what exactly `values` is, but your if is a bit strange. If `values` is list of objects, instead of comparing with `v[i] != values[ID[i]]`, you might try `!ReferenceEquals(v[i], values[ID[i]])`, but comparing objects is not common, maybe you should try to cast them to something before comparing.

Comment: @Daniel No that dose not work and values are a static list of objects and v is a object array 
`private static List<object> values = new (0);`